# How do I get the value of a table heading in relation to the td element using Jquery

Tags: html, jquery, css, html-table

## What I'm Looking To Achieve

User clicks on any < td > element in the table and is shown the Initial Gravity (IG), Final Gravity (FG) and the ABV in an output < div > Like so:

Initial Gravity: 1.024 > Final Gravity: 0.994 = 3.9% ABV.

### Breakdown

- The table's left side headers are the Initial Gravity
- The iniGrav variable should get the < th > value from the left side header of the table.
- The table's top headers are the Final Gravity
- The finGrav variable should get the < th > value from the top header of the table.
- The abv variable should get the value from the clicked < td > itself.

### My Issue

I have the rows (iniGrav) and the abv working as they should but I can't figure out how to get the finGrav value from the top header of the table. I have no idea how to find the column header value for the  that's being clicked.

In the code below I have commented out my current finGrav variable which I was trying and replaced it with "I should show finGrav"

So my current output reads:

- Initial Gravity: 1.024 > Final Gravity: ***I should show finGrav*** = 3.9% ABV

instead of

- Initial Gravity: 1.024 > Final Gravity: ***0.994*** = 3.9% ABV.

The above example imagines that the user has clicked the 3.9 < td > element seen in the image below.

[image]

How do I find my final Gravity value from the table header and give it to the finGrav variable?

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

### Code

```js
$('td').click(function() {

  // iniGrav is the Initial Gravity row of th down the left
  var iniGrav = $(this).closest("tr").find('th:eq(0)').text();


  // finGrav should be the row of headings for Final Gravity across the top
  // var finGrav = $(this).closest("table .topHead ").find('th:eq(0)').text();
  var finGrav = "I should show finGrav";


  var abv = $(this).text();
  var msg = "Initial Gravity: " + iniGrav + 
          " > Final Gravity: "  + finGrav + 
            " = " + abv + "% ABV";

  // var title = $(this).title= msg ;
  // alert(msg);

  $('#output').html(msg);
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #111;
}

#output {
  color: #fff;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

.card-body table {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

.blank-cell,
.row-1 td {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

td,
th {
  padding: 2px;
  position: relative;
  outline: 0;
}

td {
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

th {
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #0dead0;
}

td:hover {
  background: #530288;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px 0 #fff;
}

td {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
  width: 10%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  text-indent: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  position: relative;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px #111 solid;
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s linear;
  -moz-transition: 0.4s linear;
  -ms-transition: 0.4s linear;
  -o-transition: 0.4s linear;
  transition: 0.4s linear;
  -webkit-transition-property: width, background-color;
  -moz-transition-property: width, background-color;
  -ms-transition-property: width, background-color;
  -o-transition-property: width, background-color;
  transition-property: width, background-color;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.0.9/dist/boxicons.js"></script>
<link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.0.9/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
<table>


  <thead class="sticky-thead">

    <tr>
      <th>
        <i class='bx bxs-down-arrow' style='color:#ffffff'>IG</i>
        <i class='bx bxs-right-arrow' style='color:#ffffff'>FG</i>
      </th>
      <th scope="col" class="topHead" ">0.990</th>
      <th scope="col " class="topHead "">0.992</th>
      <th scope="col" class="topHead" ">0.994</th>
      <th scope="col " class="topHead "">0.996</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1.020</th>
      <td class="tool-tip">3.9</td>
      <td class="tool-tip">3.7</td>
      <td class="tool-tip">3.4</td>
      <td class="tool-tip">3.2</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1.022</th>
      <td class="tool-tip">4.2</td>
      <td class="tool-tip">3.9</td>
      <td class="tool-tip">3.7</td>
      <td class="tool-tip">3.4</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1.024</th>
      <td class="tool-tip">4.5</td>
      <td class="tool-tip">4.2</td>
      <td class="tool-tip">3.9</td>
      <td class="tool-tip">3.7</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1.026</th>
      <td class="tool-tip">4.7</td>
      <td class="tool-tip">4.5</td>
      <td class="tool-tip">4.2</td>
      <td class="tool-tip">3.9</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the index of the clicked TD, and use that to get the corresponding element in the header row.

```js
$('td').click(function() {

  // iniGrav is the Initial Gravity row of th down the left
  var iniGrav = $(this).closest("tr").find('th:eq(0)').text();

  var index = $(this).index();
  // finGrav should be the row of headings for Final Gravity across the top
  var finGrav = $(this).closest("table").find("tr:first th").eq(index).text();


  var abv = $(this).text();
  var msg = "Initial Gravity: " + iniGrav +
    " > Final Gravity: " + finGrav +
    " = " + abv + "% ABV";

  // var title = $(this).title= msg ;
  // alert(msg);

  $('#output').html(msg);
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #111;
}

#output {
  color: #fff;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

.card-body table {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

.blank-cell,
.row-1 td {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

td,
th {
  padding: 2px;
  position: relative;
  outline: 0;
}

td {
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

th {
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #0dead0;
}

td:hover {
  background: #530288;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px 0 #fff;
}

td {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
  width: 10%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  text-indent: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  position: relative;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px #111 solid;
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s linear;
  -moz-transition: 0.4s linear;
  -ms-transition: 0.4s linear;
  -o-transition: 0.4s linear;
  transition: 0.4s linear;
  -webkit-transition-property: width, background-color;
  -moz-transition-property: width, background-color;
  -ms-transition-property: width, background-color;
  -o-transition-property: width, background-color;
  transition-property: width, background-color;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.0.9/dist/boxicons.js"></script>
<link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.0.9/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
<table>


  <thead class="sticky-thead">

    <tr>
      <th>
        <i class='bx bxs-down-arrow' style='color:#ffffff'>IG</i>
        <i class='bx bxs-right-arrow' style='color:#ffffff'>FG</i>
      </th>
      <th scope="col" class="topHead">0.990</th>
      <th scope="col" class="topHead">0.992</th>
      <th scope="col" class="topHead">0.994</th>
      <th scope="col" class="topHead">0.996</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1.020</th>
      <td class="tool-tip">3.9</td>
      <td class="tool-tip">3.7</td>
      <td class="tool-tip">3.4</td>
      <td class="tool-tip">3.2</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1.022</th>
      <td class="tool-tip">4.2</td>
      <td class="tool-tip">3.9</td>
      <td class="tool-tip">3.7</td>
      <td class="tool-tip">3.4</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1.024</th>
      <td class="tool-tip">4.5</td>
      <td class="tool-tip">4.2</td>
      <td class="tool-tip">3.9</td>
      <td class="tool-tip">3.7</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1.026</th>
      <td class="tool-tip">4.7</td>
      <td class="tool-tip">4.5</td>
      <td class="tool-tip">4.2</td>
      <td class="tool-tip">3.9</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div id="output"></div>
```